# If $L^{l-1} = (l)$ for a prime integer $l$, why is $L$ a prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

[image]

This is proposition 13.2.7 from Ireland and Rosen's "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory". $\zeta_l = \zeta = e^\frac{2\pi i}{l}$ and all ideals are considered in the ring of algebraic integers of $\mathbb Q (\zeta_l)$. $e,f,g$ are, respectively, the common ramification index, common degree and number of prime ideals in $(l)$'s representation as a product of prime ideals.

How is it deduced that $L$ is prime in the second to last line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When decomposing L as a product of primes, there will be g' primes ith ramification indexes e', residual degrees f'and when raising to the power l-1, these will have to correspond to the g' primes in the decomposition of (l).
But when you identify now with the decomposition of (l), you read on the number of primes: g'=g; on the exponents: e'(l-1)=e ; f'=f.
Plugging those into efg = l-1, you get e'fg = 1 which forces e'=f=g=1: that is there is only one prime above (l) and with ramification index l-1 : it has to be L.